# Heroku toolbelt not working with rake tasks

Tags: heroku, rake, web-deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I have switched to using heroku toolbelt without issue on the command line. However, my rake tasks now fail:

```
=> Running "heroku run rake --trace db:migrate --app MYAPPNAME"
/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': heroku is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
ERROR running "heroku run rake --trace db:migrate --app MYAPPNAME"
/Users/USERNAME/Code/luxr/lib/shell.rb:35:in `execute'
/Users/USERNAME/Code/luxr/lib/tasks/deploy_tasks.rake:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The same command `heroku run rake --trace db:migrate --app MYAPPNAME` works without issue typed directly into the command line.

Ideas?

UPDATE: I have heroku toolbelt installed, but I noticed it's on ruby 1.9.3 and my app is 1.9.2p290, is that causing the issue?

```
$ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.34.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

Comment: it doesn't seem you use toolbelt.. it is looking for the gem. do `heroku version` to see what is running

Comment: I installed toolbelt already: `heroku-toolbelt/2.34.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3` I now notice it's on 1.9.3 and my app is 1.9.2p290....is that the difference?

Comment: Does running `NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 heroku run rake ...` work?

Answer (score 1):

Running the heroku command with `Bundler.with_clean_env` worked for me. If the rake task you want to run is called `cache_flush`, wrap your call to heroku toolbelt with `Bundler.with_clean_env`

```
task :cache_flush  do
     Bundler.with_clean_env { p `heroku --help` }
end
```

Comment: How is this done.. where does this bit of code belong?